# 7) Prove that $2n-3 \leq 2^{n-2}$ for all $n \geq 5$ by mathematical induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

Prove that $2n-3\leq 2^{n-2}$ , for all $n \geq 5$ by mathematical induction

I have to prove by mathematical induction that: $2n-3\leq 2^{n-2}$ , for all $n \geq 5$

Comment: Review of what? At the very least the base case you should show us (substituting $n=5$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=5$ you have
$$ 8=2^{5-2} \geq 2\cdot5-3 = 7$$
So the statement is *correct* for $n=5$

Now assume $2^{n-2} \geq 2n-3$ is valid for some fixed $n$ then for $n+1$ you will get:

$$2^{n-1} = 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2} \geq 2^{n-2} +2 \stackrel{assumption}{\geq}2n-3+2 = 2(n+1)-3$$

Thus
$$2^{n-2} \geq 2n-3 \Longrightarrow 2^{n-1} \geq 2(n+1)-3$$
which means the statement is correct for every $n\geq5$